# How to configure Parallels Plesk 11 to use Google DNS server

Tags: google, dns-server

The "default" DNS server does not recognize certain host names, and as a result we are unable to send emails to these domains. We would like to use Google DNS server (8.8.8.8), as it does the work. I've tried to make the 8.8.8.8 a master DNS server, but no results so far.

Comment: Contact Parallels.

Comment: what have you "tried"? you don't give us enough here to help you.  See [this Meta topic](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault) for some tips on how to improve your question...

Answer (score 3):

You can't set this in Plesk. You have to set this manually by editing your /etc/resolv.conf .